# speedup/optimize very slow db2 query with JOIN on multiple rows and 2 ON clauses

Tags: join, db2, ibm-cloud, query-performance

I have one table1 like:

```
TIME                   NAMES
2017-12-19 00:00:00    a
2017-12-19 00:00:00    b
2017-12-19 00:00:00    c
2017-12-19 00:00:00    d
...
2017-12-19 00:01:00    a
2017-12-19 00:01:00    b
2017-12-19 00:01:00    c
2017-12-19 00:01:00    d
...
```

---> more than 100k different TIMES and about 100 different NAMES

and a second table2 like:

```
TIME                   NAMES    VALUES
2017-12-19 00:00:00    a        1
2017-12-19 00:00:00    c        2
...
2017-12-19 00:01:00    b        4
2017-12-19 00:01:00    c        5
2017-12-19 00:01:00    d        6
...
```

---> also a high amount of different TIMES and different NAMES with VALUES

To combine both tables I use:

```
SELECT table1.time, table1.names, table2.values
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
ON table2.time = table1.time AND table2.NAMES = table1.NAMES
ORDER BY time ASC;
```

But this is very slow.
Is there a better solution?

Comment: Did you run the index-advisor or tuning-tools to check for recommendations? e.g an index per table (name, time) ?

Comment: Agree with @mao about the tools/index checking, this should be a relatively simple and trivial query for a database.